# OpenPyXL を使い、特定文字列を検索し、横のセルに任意の値を入れたいと考えています。

Tags: python, openpyxl

Pythonの超初心者でございます。

openpyxlを使い用意されたエクセルを読み込み、
特定の文字を含むセルの横に任意の数字を入力したいと考えおります。

下記の画像においては、「ターゲット」としていますが、特定文字列を含む場合に、
横のセルに任意の数字を入力したいと思っております。

実現するアイデアがあれば、ご教示いただければと思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: やりたいことをコードにすれば良いかと思いますが、具体的には何に困っているのでしょうか？

Comment: 現状だと単に "仕様" が書かれているのみで、何に困っているのかが読み取れません。自分で決めた仕様に従って、Python の文法や OpenPyXL の使い方を調べながらプログラムを書くだけだと思うので、もう少し具体的に困りごとを書いた方がアドバイスが付きやすいです。

Comment: 検索して見つかるこんな記事が参考になるでしょう。[ExcelをPython（openpyxl）で操作する - セルの読み書き](https://www.soudegesu.com/post/python/cell-excel-with-openpyxl/), [【Python】openpyxlを利用したエクセルのセルとシートの範囲指定で読み取りと書き込み](https://genchan.net/it/programming/python/3069/), [【Python】openpyxlでExcelから読み込み・書き込みする方法【数式の結果を取得する方法も解説】](https://www.self-study-blog.com/dokugaku/python-excel-openpyxl-cell-value-data/) あるいはVBAなら自分でも出来る(方法を知っている/探せる)とかなら、それを元に変換してみるとか。

Answer (score 1):

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("test.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
target_col = "A"
next_col = "B"
target_string = "ターゲット"
for row in range(2, ws.max_row+1):
    if target_string in str(ws[f"{target_col}{row}"].value):
        ws[f"{next_col}{row}"] = 1
wb.save("test_copy.xlsx")
```